# iptables to allow only first udp packet and drop remaining all udp packets for next 10 seconds

Tags: udp, iptables

How to make iptable to allow only first udp packet from a source and block subsequent packets from that source for next 10 seconds.
On a linux server receives first udp packet from the client, if response is delayed by 100 ms, client is keep on sending request packet for every 100ms until client receives response.
To avoid this, at server only first packet must be received and subsequent packets should be dropped.
I tried dropping first 4 packets and responding to only 5th packet using below iptables.

iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m recent --name attack --set

iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m recent --name attack --rcheck --seconds 10 --hitcount 4 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -j DROP

Comment: I don't know why you want to do this, but that sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. At server getting more than 1 duplicate packet but we are serving all packets and do not have control on received packets. Hence it would be great if we receive only first packet and ignore all packets reaching within next 10 seconds.